# How can I redirect error messages to the browser in CGI/Ruby?

Tags: ruby, cgi

I've been using CGI/Perl for a while and have got used to using Carp to redirect error messages to the browser with something like:

```
use CGI::Carp qw(warningsToBrowser fatalsToBrowser set_message);
set_message("Please report this error to the administrator");

...

warningsToBrowser(1);
```

I'm considering making the switch to using Ruby instead of Perl, but I can't find a way to do a similar error redirection. Is there a Ruby module which can do this?

Comment: Are you using Rails? Because there's an ActiveSupport Rescuable module that does something similar - http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Thanks but no, I'm just using plain Ruby

Comment: This question doesn't seem to be related to Perl so I've removed the tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 group :development do
    gem 'better_errors'
    gem 'binding_of_caller'
    gem 'meta_request'
end
```

See this railscast: [Better Errors & RailsPanel](http://railscasts.com/episodes/402-better-errors-railspanel?view=asciicast) and this thread [redirect errors to browser in ruby + cgi](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.ruby/GfPfMBbnCfw), where it suggests this:

```
$stdout.sync = true
$stderr.reopen $stdout
puts "Content-type: text/html\n\n"`
```

The content-type needs to be early in the code, as any errors before it will not be sent to the browser.

Comment: Thanks! The second link is the key one for me, somewhere in there it suggests setting `$stdout.sync = true` so I'll edit the reply with that.